# How to make a pure javascript .css() function using variable variables

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have been working on a jQuery-like JavaScript library. The next function I would like to add is a `.css()` function.

Something like this:

```
function css(elem,name,value){
   elem.style.name = value;
   //   >>>>   ^   <<<<<<
   // needed variable variable
}
```

Anyone know what I should do? I am at a loss, I have been Goggling suggestions for the past hour and I haven't come up a solution.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: @Pointy Oh, I hadn't seen that. If I had, I wouldn't have asked this question. But as I said, I have been Goggling for the past hour.

Comment: You've googled this for an hour and couldn't find the answer? That's hard to believe. I searched "get object property using variable", and the first result (and many more) showed how.

Comment: @BlueSkies Well, I hadn't searched that specifically. I had been searching things along the lines of `JavaScript variable variables`.

Comment: Searching "JavaScript variable variables" gives the solution as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're looking for bracket notation:

```
function css(elem,name,value){
    elem.style[name] = value;
}
```