# Pure javascript equivalent to jquery assignment

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've been trying to figure out the proper syntax for the pure JavaScript version of this JQuery code.

```
$('body').css('margin-bottom', $('footer').height());
```

So far what I have is:

```
var body = document.getElementById('#body');
var footer = document.getElementById('#footer');

body.style.marginBottom = footer.style.height;
```

This assignment only works if I define the footer height in JavaScript.

I'm aware of this question [How to make a pure javascript .css() function using variable variables [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19848431/how-to-make-a-pure-javascript-css-function-using-variable-variables) and the questions similar to it, but still am unable to get it correct. I know I could just use JQuery, but I don't see the value in loading a whole library to do very simple things.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you tried footer.offsetHeight? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/offsetHeight

Comment: Have you tried removing the hash in front of the id? getElementById('body')

Comment: Or changing `document.getElementById('#body')` to `document.querySelector('#body')`

Comment: @battery.cord `#body` will not work, as the id of the body is not 'body'.

Comment: Are you executing these lines on `document.onload= function(){...}`? Maybe your footer have no height because page isn't loaded yet.

Comment: @Piwwoli Are you sure? The original users code sure seems to be trying to get the body element by id of body only he switched code from jQuery to pure JS and never removed the #.

Comment: @battery.cord I actually gave the body element a body id tag just to make sure.

Answer (score 1):

Open JavaScript console and type `console.log(document.body.style)` to see all style attributes that `document.body` has. Also I think it's `document.body` and not just `body`.

Body seems to have the following margin properties:

```
margin: ""
marginBottom: ""
marginLeft: ""
marginRight: ""
marginTop: ""
```

So `document.body.style.marginBottom = '15px'` should work for example. Remember that you must specify the unit, like `px`.

Answer (score 0):

Use offsetHeight:

```
body.style.marginBottom = footer.offsetHeight;
```